# change "and" for "y" in \citeA [apacite]

Tags: citing, apa-style, apacite

Am using `\usepackage[notocbib]{apacite}` for cites in my document.

When I use the `\citeA` command, I need to change "Author1 **'and'** Author2, (Year)" to "Author1 **'y'** Author2, (Year)".

I have tried:

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand{\BBAB}{y}
  \renewcommand{\BBAA}{y}
  \renewcommand{\BAnd}{y}
}
```

But nothing happens.

Thank you for your answers,

Carlos

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you consider using `biblatex`? It is language-aware.

Comment: Thank you! I think eventually i will have to change to biblatec.

Update: using \usepackage[spanish]{babel} changes 'and' for 'y', but also '&' to 'y'.

Comment: In biblatex, it can be changed, patching the biblatex macros, but we need a full compilable code which shows the problem.